# converter JSON em objeto

Tags: javascript, json

**Tenho o seguinte json**

```
[
    {"name":"razao_social","value":"INTELIDER"},
    {"name":"nome_fantasia","value":"INTELIDER LTDA"},
    {"name":"cpf_cnpj","value":"10.999.558/0001-86"},
    {"name":"rg_insc_estadual","value":"132456789"},
    {"name":"login","value":"gleyson"},
    {"name":"senha","value":"123456"},
    {"name":"confirma_senha","value":"S"}
]
```

**preciso converter para o objeto abaixo:**

```
[
  {
      "razao_social": "INTELIDER",
      "nome_fantasia": "INTELIDER LTDA",
      "cpf_cnpj": "10999558000186",
      "rg_insc_estadual": "132456789",
      "usuario":       {
         "login": "gleyson",
         "senha": "123456",
         "ativo": "S"
      },
   }
]
```

**Hiago me passou o seguinte código:**

```
$('.form').submit(function () {
      var dados = jQuery(this).serializeArray();
      var obj = {};
      $.each(dados, function (i,obj) {
          obj[obj.name] = obj.value;
      });

      obj.usuario = {
            login: obj.login,
            senha: obj.senha,
            ativo: obj.confirma_senha
      };

      var json = JSON.stringify([obj]);
      alert(json);
      return false;
 });
```

No final o retorno é vazio [{"usuario":{}}], porém debugando vejo que o array dados esta preenchido corretamente, ele tambem entra na $.each, e carrega os valores passa os valores e zera um por um.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso não funciona porque estás a usar o mesmo nome `obj` de variável dentro e fora da função.

Em ves de

```
  var obj = {};
  $.each(dados, function (i,obj) {
      obj[obj.name] = obj.value;
  });
```

usa

```
  var obj = {};
  $.each(dados, function (i, dado) {
      obj[dado.name] = dado.value;
  });
```

ou mais simples:

```
var obj = dados.reduce(function(obj, dado){
    obj[dado.name] = dado.value;
    return obj;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a seguinte lógica para montar direto o objeto com o objeto usuário dentro:

```
var json = {};
var usuario = {};
$.each(obj, function(i, dado){
   if($.inArray(dado.name, ["login", "senha", "confirma_senha"]) > -1 ){
     usuario[dado.name] = dado.value;
   } else {
     json[dado.name] = dado.value;
   }
});
json["usuario"] = usuario;
```